# CryptGenRandom Entropy

Tags: windows, winapi, random, entropy

CryptGenRandom is a random number generator function in CryptoAPI in Windows. How much entropy has that random number generator ? I have already looked a lot, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Also see [Cryptanalysis of the Random Number Generator of the Windows Operating System](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/419.pdf) by Leo Dorrendor.

Answer (score 11):

The exact algorithm of Windows CryptGenRandom was never published, therefore, some security experts suggest not to use it at all.

Some reverse-engineering and cryptanalysis was made.
A published research ([Cryptanalysis of the Windows Random Number Generator - Leo Dorrendorf, 2007](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~dolev/pubs/thesis/msc-thesis-leo.pdf)) examined Windows 2000 RNG and found a number of
weaknesses in the design and implementation.

The document also describes the entropy collector mechanism of the algorithm (section 4.2.3). The Entropy sources are:

```
Source                   Bytes requested
CircularHash              256
KSecDD                    256
GetCurrentProcessID()       8
GetCurrentThreadID()        8
GetTickCount()              8
GetLocalTime()             16
QueryPerformanceCounter()  24
GlobalMemoryStatus()       16
GetDiskFreeSpace()         40
GetComputerName()          16
GetUserName()             257
GetCursorPos()              8
GetMessageTime()           16
NTQuerySystemInformation calls:
ProcessorTimes             48
Performance               312
Exception                  16
Lookaside                  32
ProcessorStatistics       up to the remaining length (3584 bytes buffer)
ProcessesAndThreads       up to the remaining length
```

Since we are talking about a pseudo-number-generator and not a real-number-generator, you may say that there is no real entropy at all, or count only the sources that you may consider as "entropy" (pseudo-entropy).

I was unable to find information regarding newer versions on Windows.

Comment: what's about Windows Vista/7/8 entropy?

Comment: The research link is bad. Can you adjust?

Comment: A presentation is also available: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/COURSE/PRIVACY/pinkas_prg_insecurity.ppt

Comment: This is a very good answer! I really like your systematic approach. How can you determine the *bytes requested* for each algorithm? The *performance*'s inspection has a very high proportion in the overall entropy (312 bits). Can you explain why?  - - It would love to get your systematic approach also for the image analysis generally because I cannot find any quality preview about any algorithm, etc here http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4935/10350